# Fixed Step in Chart in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, teechart, c++builder-xe

There is a TChart component in C++ Builde with one serie.

I add the data using AddXY method but I want the Y-Axis to have fixed minimum and maximum values and fixed step. I've managed to understand how the first two things are done.

So my question is: How can I define a fixed step for the Y-Axis in TChart component.

*Important:* I've tried using Increment property but it gives me distance from the origin and that's not what I want.

```
Chart1->LeftAxis->Automatic = false;
Chart1->LeftAxis->Minimum = M - 2 * S;
Chart1->LeftAxis->Maximum = M + 2 * S;
Chart1->LeftAxis->Increment = S;
```

**Update**: I'll try to explain more clearly what I want to be. After I defined the minimum and maximum for the chart, I want to make a fixed step for this. The code I posted above doesn't work properly *because* I need a fixed step beginning from *Minimum* value and not from *zero* value as the code in question does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question. I appreciate that you were helping me. Thank you.

I just needed to change the    Items    propery of the axis.

Instead of Increment one should use

```
Chart1->LeftAxis->Items->Clear();
Chart1->LeftAxis->Items->Add(double Value);
```